# Código Javascript continúa ejecutándose a pesar de cumplir el condicional else if

Tags: javascript, condiciones, function, else

La intención de este algoritmo es limitar el número de cuotas a pagar a 12, y para ello se generó un bloque if else delimitando el rango de 9 a 12 cuotas y luego otro en donde, si eran mas de 12 las cuotas colocadas por el usuario, se ejecute un alert con el mensaje "La cantidad de cuotas máximas es de 12". Esto se logró, sin embargo, el código continua ejecutándose y arroja otro alert con el monto del valor del crédito a solicitar por el usuario. Quisiera saber como podría hacer para que si el número de cuotas es mayor a 12 arroje únicamente el alert de "La cantidad de cuotas máximas es de 12" y no se siga leyendo el código o, como otra opción, volver a solicitar el numero de cuotas de nuevo.

```
let valorCredito = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el monto a solicitar"));

let cuotas = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese la cantidad de cuotas"));

let interes1 = 0.10, interes2 = 0.20, interes3 = 0.30, interes4 = 0.40;

let calculoInteres= ' ';

function multiplicar (valor1,valor2) {
    return valor1 * valor2;
}

if(cuotas<=3) {
calculoInteres = multiplicar (valorCredito,interes1);
}

else if (cuotas<=6) {
    calculoInteres = multiplicar (valorCredito,interes2);
}

else if(cuotas<=9) {
    calculoInteres = multiplicar (valorCredito,interes3);
}

else if (cuotas>9) {
    calculoInteres = multiplicar (valorCredito,interes4);
}


function sumar (a,b) {

montoFinal = a + b;

}

sumar(valorCredito,calculoInteres);

alert("El monto final a pagar es:" + " " + montoFinal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo modificaría la parte final de tu código, cambiando de lugar la alerta y añadiendo una nueva condicional.

```
if(cuotas > 12) alert('Las cuotas son mayores a 12')
else sumar(valorCredito ,calculoInteres)

function sumar (credito, interes) {
    montoFinal = credito + interes;
    alert("El monto final a pagar es:" + " " + montoFinal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que quieres, sin modificar mucho tu código podes usar un do...while cuando vas a consultar la cantidad de cuotas:

```
let cuotas = 0;
let mensajeCuotas = "Ingrese la cantidad de cuotas";

do {
  cuotas = parseInt(prompt(mensajeCuotas));
  mensajeCuotas = "La cantidad de cuotas máximas es de 12";
} while (!cuotas || cuotas < 1 || cuotas > 12);
```

Y también deberías modificar el final de la función, ya que nunca estas inicializando la variable monto final, ni estas retornando el valor:

```
function sumar(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

const montoFinal = sumar(valorCredito, calculoInteres);

alert("El monto final a pagar es: " + montoFinal);
```